# Trim() method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string as the following.

```
\n
\n
line 1
\n
\n
line 2
\n
\n
line 3
\n
\n
```

I want to remove only start \n and end \n just llike php trim()

I want result is

```
line 1
\n
\n
line 2
\n
\n
line 3
```

How do I do?

```
text.gsub(/^[\s]+|[\s]+$/, '')
```

will remove all \n

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text.strip
```

........................................